# Dynamic Paypal Payment Buttons In PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, paypal

Finding useful Paypal payment information and documentation has to be one of the hardest things, Paypal themselves don't let you create dynamic payment buttons that are also encrypted.

Does anyone know of any scripts or useful documentation that will help me create dynamic paypal payment buttons that are encrypted or use $_POST to prevent users from tampering?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php